# collection answers by inserting them into a dataframe or vector

Tags: r

I am wondering if it is possible to groupe a bunch of different calculation answers into a vector? I have 30 calculations (I displayed the answer of the first 3 here), and than I would like to groupe them all inside a vector or even data frame so the stock name stays. The goal being to sort them by descending price

```
             AXP.Close
2002-06-20 0.008553863
```

2nd answer I would like to insert inside the vector or even data frame

```
             BA.Close
2002-06-20 0.01553576
```

3rd answer I would like to insirt inside the vector or even data frame

```
            DIS.Close
2002-06-20 0.01073620
```

More details

thank you both of you for your answers, you're right I should give some more details:

So basicly I am trying to calculate and sort descending the yield of the 30 stocks in the Dow jones Index, I can't use the yahooQF("Dividend Yield") because it doesn't have the option to choose the yield in 2002 for example

```
x = c("AAPL","ADBE","ADP")
Yield<-getQuote(x, what = yahooQF("Dividend Yield"))
```

So I tried to get it otherwise by getting separately the dividend over a year time span and the price at the end of the period to than do a division

```
s = c("VOD","ADP", etc)
getSymbols(s, from="2009-06-20", to="2009-06-22")
ClosePrices <- do.call(merge, lapply(s, function(x) Cl(get(x))))
sum(getDividends("ADP",from = "2008-06-29", to="2009-06-20")) /ClosePrices[,1]
```

And now the objective would be to put them all the calculated yields in a vector (the name of the stock should stay) and order them descending wise! Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll make something that looks like you describe:

```
s <- c("AXP", "BA", "DIS")
getSymbols(s, src='yahoo', from='2012-06-19', to='2012-06-20')
L <- lapply(s, function(x) ROC(Cl(get(x)), na.pad=FALSE))
L
[[1]]
             AXP.Close
2012-06-20 0.008742843

[[2]]
              BA.Close
2012-06-20 0.001233468

[[3]]
             DIS.Close
2012-06-20 0.004619916
```

Now, combine the results by column

```
do.call(cbind, L)
             AXP.Close    BA.Close   DIS.Close
2012-06-20 0.008742843 0.001233468 0.004619916
```

This is equivalent to `cbind(L[[1]], L[[2]], L[[3]])` but will work for any length list.

---

To address your edit.  I think this will do what you want with the Dow 30

```
# make a simple function to get the names of the DJIA components
DJIcomponents <- function() {
    require("XML")
    djicomp <- readHTMLTable('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=^DJI+Components', 
                             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    data.frame(djicomp[[tail(grep("Symbol", djicomp), 1)]])
}
s <- DJIcomponents()$Symbol

getSymbols(s, src='yahoo', from="2009-06-20", to="2009-06-22")
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(s, function(sym) {
    sum(getDividends(sym, from = "2008-06-29", to="2009-06-20"))/Cl(get(sym, pos=.GlobalEnv))
}))
```

Now, put in decreasing order

```
out[1, order(out[1, ], decreasing=TRUE)]
             GE.Close  BAC.Close  PFE.Close   DD.Close    T.Close
2009-06-22 0.08940972 0.08207705 0.07572684 0.06804979 0.06708075
            MRK.Close   VZ.Close   AA.Close  CAT.Close  CVX.Close
2009-06-22 0.06036537 0.06029314 0.05389222 0.05191595 0.03953771
             HD.Close  JPM.Close INTC.Close  MMM.Close   BA.Close
2009-06-22 0.03870968 0.03620322 0.03571429 0.03514877 0.03496802
            KFT.Close  JNJ.Close   KO.Close  MCD.Close   PG.Close
2009-06-22 0.03445545 0.03369977 0.03292353 0.03277972 0.03243671
           AXP.Close  TRV.Close  UTX.Close  XOM.Close MSFT.Close
2009-06-22 0.0309944 0.02922552 0.02805249 0.02353283 0.02147766
            WMT.Close  IBM.Close  DIS.Close   HPQ.Close CSCO.Close
2009-06-22 0.02103313 0.01961347 0.01544572 0.008479067          0
```

Comment: amazing how close you could get with so little info! I edited my post question with a lot more details if you could take a quick look it would be great! Thank you really appreciate your help

Comment: Even god couldn't have done better! thanks a million that's really great work you did there for me!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of code that generates these answers. The simplest way to put them all into a vector is:

```
v = c(AXP.Close=AXP.Close, BA.Close=BA.Close...)
```

*However*, based on the similarity between your calculations, which look like they are each closing prices of a stock, my guess is that each calculation is almost exactly the same. In that case, you certainly shouldn't be generating them with separate code and then putting them all into a vector- you should be generating them using a `for` loop- or, even better, with a call to `sapply`.

Can you give any more details about your calculations?

Also: what form are the data in currently? It looks like they are associated with both a date and a stock name.